# Please update answer to forum software question

Tags: discussion

Several years ago, there was a comprehensive q & a about forum software: [What forum software should I use?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/25771/what-forum-software-should-i-use)

Could this please be updated?

I am particularly interested in hearing what the current consensus is about the following: Vanilla, SMF, Codoforum, Flarem.  I saw that Vanilla, as a WordPress plugin, only got 3 out of 5 stars.

Any new entries in the field?

I'm looking for free, easy to use, good support.

Comment: If you have specific requirements what the forum software should be able to do, you can ask for a recommendation on [softwarerecs.se].

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you would like to see a question updated with newer information the correct course of action is to add a [bounty](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/help/bounty) to it. Bounties are used to bring extra attention to questions by offering a substantial award for a great answer.

Comment: I'm a little nervous about doing this, because of my beginning level rep on this site.  This is a site I may want to learn more from in future; but I don't have much expertise to share here.  I noticed that you, on the other hand, are at 80k.  If you share my impression that an update to the question referenced would be useful to others, would you consider setting the bounty for me?

Comment: I don't see how my, or your, reputation will affect your learning from this site. Your ability to learn from this site is unaffected by your reputation. Believe me, the history of this shows that if you add a bounty to that question, it will get more answers. It doesn't matter who offers it.

Comment: I have very few rep points on this site and would like to hold onto them.  50 rep points are a lot to lose to a bounty when you are starting with only 100.

Comment: If you aren't willing to give up artificial internet points to get that information, how important is it to you really?

Comment: Wouldn't you think twice before posting a 40k bounty?

Comment: Depends on what I needed to know. :) At a site like [so] rep can be useful as it can attract potential employers. But the rep here literally means *nothing*. And at both sites it's just artificial internet points. The only value it has is what you give it. Spend it and get something that does have value like new knowledge.

Comment: When you go below a certain number, your ability to do things (such as post comments) gets pretty severely curtailed.

Comment: The only privilege you would lose is the ability to set bounties (and comment although you are one upvote away from getting that back). That's it. (And kinda ironic).

Comment: Okay, I bit the bullet and started a bounty.

Comment: Sigh.  I lost the ability to comment at the main webmasters site.  That's what I was afraid of.